# What happens if i define get and dont define anything inside set for property in C#

Tags: c#, properties

```
    public Format format
    {
        get
        {
            if (format == Format.NONE)
            {
                this.findFormat();
            }
            return this.format;
        }

        set
        {
            ;
        }
    }
```

what happens if i do such a thing. Set nothing is defined.  I am doing so because i only want to do some processing when someone wants to get format. I want set to work as default

Comment: Please go through in this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: Well, then you cant set the value.

Comment: So what should i do if i want to define get by my self and want set to work as default?

Comment: Your code is not valid in first place. It will be recursive call if you call 'format' property.

Comment: His code is valid. `findFormat` probably assigns `format` a new value. @eocron06

Comment: @eocron06 why will it be a recursive call. My find format actually analyses some string variable and decides which format it is. Where is the recursive call??

Comment: You calling 'format' getter from 'format' getter in very first line. This will StackOverflow on first call to your getter.

Answer (score 0):

If you write an empty set block, nothing will happen when you try to set the property.

From the comments,

> So what should I do if I want to define get by my self and want set to work as default?

Unfortunately, the only way I can think of is not very clean. You need to use a backing variable:

```
private Format format;

public Format Format {
    get {
        if (format == Format.NONE)
        {
            this.findFormat();
        }
        return this.format;
    }

    set {
        format = value;
    }
}
```